# C# - Make copy of a big class (model) by value not reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, class, oop

I do project by asp.net core mvc. when I do copy of the model and change its values, the values of the original model is changing too because it made copy of the model by reference, so the value place in data is same.
I need way that I can do copy for values of the model doesn't connect with original model.

Comment: Copy or project each property into a new object or use automapper or serialization, either way this has been asked and searched for a lot

Answer (score 2):

Your question could have many answers depending on the encapsulation of the object you are copying. I will assume you are operating on a low level entity object rather than an object that is supposed to encapsulate it. If this assumption is incorrect and it is a higher level object that encapsulates entity operations I will gently remind you of good programming practices: [Martin Fowler - TellDontAsk](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html).

For the answer I will use the class below to illustrate:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
}
```

I assume what is happening is something similar to the following:

```
Student john = new Student();
Student jane = john;

jane.FirstName = "Jane"; // now john.FirstName == "Jane"
```

What you are going to need to do is clone the object to a new object instance. There are various ways to do that.

Option #1:

```
// Create a new entity object manually assigning each value
// from the first object to the value in the new object.
var clonedStudent = new Student
{
    Id = john.Id, // Copies value not reference
    LastName = john.LastName, // string is immutable this OK
    FirstName = john.FirstName, // string is immutable this OK
    // DateTime is a struct I think so it should pass value
    EnrollmentDate = john.EnrollmentDate // Verify my assumption
};
```

Option #2:

```
// Make Student class partial and extend it with clone method.
// This is helpful for generated entities not using the code-first approach.
public partial class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
}

public partial class Student
{
    public Student Clone()
    {
        return new Student
        {
            Id = Id, // Copies value not reference
            LastName = LastName, // string is immutable this OK
            FirstName = FirstName, // string is immutable this OK
            // DateTime is a struct I think so it should pass value
            EnrollmentDate = EnrollmentDate, // Verify my assumption
        };
    }
}
```

To use it you would write:

```
Student clonedStudent = john.Clone();
```

Option #3: You could use a NuGet package that does the cloning for you. There are various ones that do that. A quick google search pulled up this one for me. [DeepCloner](https://github.com/force-net/DeepCloner)

If you are copying objects from one type to another you might want to use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

NOTE: Also, based on your question a good knowledge of how entity framework handles changes might be useful.

[Tracking vs. No-Tracking Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking)

Hopefully that helps.

Happy coding!!!

Comment: my Class is so big and contine othet classes inside it, I can't pass every item alone.

Comment: I just wanna copy value when I do: Class2=Class1;

Comment: A user-defined type cannot overload the assignment operator to do what you are wanting it to do. However, a user-defined type can define an implicit conversion to another type. So the answer is to use one of the methods specified above. Please ask another question on how to do implicit conversion if you are not sure about that and want to try that.

Answer (score 0):

option 1 use AutoMapper

option 2 create Copy using Reflection

```
        public class PropertyCopier<TParent, TChild> where TParent : class
                                       where TChild : class
    {
        public static void Copy(TParent parent, TChild child)
        {
            var parentProperties = parent.GetType().GetProperties();
            var childProperties = child.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (var parentProperty in parentProperties)
            {
                foreach (var childProperty in childProperties)
                {
                    if (parentProperty.Name == childProperty.Name && parentProperty.PropertyType == childProperty.PropertyType)
                    {
                        childProperty.SetValue(child, parentProperty.GetValue(parent));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).